# Filter out headers of AMQP message in AMQP inbound adapter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-amqp

Given I have `IntegrationFlow`:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(
    Amqp.inboundAdapter(rabbitConnectionFactory, NTF_INCOMING_CMSF_EVENT_QUEUE)
            .messageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(jacksonObjectMapper))
)
    .get()
```

I'd like to apply [HeaderFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/transformer/HeaderFilter.html) to the AMQP inbound adapter, but it seems I can only do it later in the pipeline.

Is it possible to filter headers in inbound adapter?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but that is called already a `HeaderMapper`.

See these options of that `Amqp.inboundAdapter()`:

```
/**
 * Configure the adapter's {@link AmqpHeaderMapper};
 * defaults to {@link DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper}.
 * @param headerMapper the headerMapper.
 * @return the spec.
 */
public S headerMapper(AmqpHeaderMapper headerMapper) {
    this.target.setHeaderMapper(headerMapper);
    return _this();
}

/**
 * Only applies if the default header mapper is used.
 * @param headers the headers.
 * @return the spec.
 * @see DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper#setRequestHeaderNames(String[])
 */
public S mappedRequestHeaders(String... headers) {
```

For further details see `DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper` JavaDocs and this respective reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-message-headers

So, probably what you need is a negation operator (`!`) on header name patterns.